# Architecting a collection of related items of different types

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

```
public class Base : ICustomItem
{
}

public class Book : Base
{
    public List<Author> Authors;
    public List<Bookmark> Bookmarks;
}

public class Author : Base
{
}

public class Bookmark : Base
{
}

public ObservableCollection(ICustomItem) MyItems;

public ListCollectionView MyItemsView { get; } = new ListCollectionView(MyItems);
```

With a setup like this, I can show a singular list containing books, authors, and bookmarks. I can drill down into a book, and see that specific books authors and bookmarks.

Problem #1: I'd like to drill down into an author, and see all of the authors books.  On top of that, I'd like to see all the bookmarks for all the books by that author.

An easy solution is to add the appropriate lists to each other class.  eg.
`public List<Book> Books` to the `Author` class.  However, this gets out of hand when you start adding more categories (eg. `Genre`, `Publisher`, `Language`, etc)

Problem 2: I'd also like to be able to sort my list by the number of any selected tag, including any relevant tag type:

`MyItemsView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Bookmarks.Count", Descending);`

The number of bookmarks an author has should be the sum of all the bookmarks for all their books.

What is a good way to architect this kind of data so as to not have to maintain multiple lookup collections for every type?  Is using `Book` as a source of truth not a good approach?  Ideally I'd be able to sort by any tag type.

In my real application, I have solved problem #1: when drilling down into eg. an `Author`, I find all the `Book` in `MyItems` with a matching author, and then pull all the `Genre`, `Publisher`, etc from the list of books pulled.  In this way I can display all the tags an author has based on the tags their books provided. (I do this in the scope of my list view model, as I know which item I am drilling down into and have access to the main `MyItems` collection)

However, using this approach I can't seem to solve problem #2. To be able to sort on `Bookmarks.Count`, I need to move it into `Base` and somehow populate it for each relevant tag type.

How can I expose this kind of information to each non-`Book` tag type without giving each `Author` or `Bookmark` access to the global item collection (which feels like a big no-no), or maintaining lists of all relevant tags for each tag type (which just feels really painfully inefficient)?

Edit 1:
Can you define "tag" and "tag type" and give a few more examples?

I'm using tag to define any kind of item i'd like to put into my list. A `Book`, an `Author`, a `Bookmark` are all tags. `Language` and `Genre` would also be tags.  A book has authors, and languages, just like a language has books and authors.

Edit2:
Even if you don't plan to have a backing database, you should benefit from brushing up on your Entity-Relationship Model knowledge

I understand this is a highly relational structure.  I do have a backing database but how it is stored in the database has little relevance with how to structure the data to be bound to a `ListCollectionView`

Comment: Can you define "tag" and "tag type" and give a few more examples?

Comment: Even if you don't plan to have a backing database, you should benefit from brushing up on your [Entity-Relationship Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) knowledge.

Comment: You're going to have to improve this overly broad question to get the attention you seek. A small snippet of incomplete code and a wall of text is not going to clarify the overall problem.

Comment: Moreover,  although you tagged your question `mvvm` and `data-binding`, it is important to notice that, as a process, you're one step (or two) *before* that.

Comment: I have provided enough code to attempt what I am asking.  Create a unified list of books, authors, and bookmarks, and then sort the list by total bookmarks.  An authors bookmark count is the sum total of bookmarks made in books they've written.  A books bookmark count is obvious.  A bookmarks bookmark count is 1.

Comment: Maintain the ability to view the details of any item, details being comprised of all the relevant tags. eg: if viewing the details of a `Language`, be able to see all the `Book`s in that language, as well as all the `Author`s of all those books.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm bit confused... You wrote: `how it is stored in the database has little relevance with how to structure the data to be bound to a ListCollectionView` - Seems, you don't understand [MVVM design pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/). Data presentation (`View`) is not the same as `Model`. The `ViewModel` acts as interface between `Model` and `View`. On the other hand, all of your classes, such as `Author`, `Bookmark` and `Book` may inherit from a base class. This is a power of OOP!

Comment: to all those commenting on databases: you do not need a circular data structure in a database. you do not need live updating.  while there are similar concepts, how you store information in your database does not affect how you structure your view models for binding programmatically. i feel like the rest of the comments saying i do not understand mvvm are completely missing the complexity of this ask.  it is precisely because i do understand mvvm i am asking these questions.please imagine adding far more tag types then i've outlined in this example and how that grows the problem

Comment: You could associate a dictionary with tag and value with a book but I think most of the things you have listed should be properties. Author and Bookmark have other attributes. You could ALSO have tags but personally I think they are best suited to things you cannot predict initially and are user added.  You can predict people that people will definitely be interested in all the properties you have listed. PS A book can have multiple authors so a book would have a list<author>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd want the relationships between types to be as ethereal as possible. While most types are easily relatable, some have compound keys or odd relationships, and you just never know...so I'd externalize the finding of related types from the types themselves. Only a lucky few of us have a globally unique consistent key type.

I could imagine letting all your types be both observers and observable. I've never done such a thing out loud...at least, not like this, but it's an interesting possibility...and given 500 points, I figured it would be worth noodling around with ;-)

I'm using the term `Tag` to kinda follow your commentary. Maybe `Base` makes more sense to you? Anyway, in the following, a `Tag` is a type that notifies observing tags and listens to observable tags. I made the `observables` be a list of `Tag.Subscription`. Normally, you would just have a list of `IDisposable` instances, since that's all an observable typically provides. The reason for this is that `Tag.Subscription` lets you discover the underlying `Tag`...so that you can scrape your subscriptions for your types' list properties in derived types (as shown below in a `Author` and `Book`.)

I set up the `Tag` subscriber/notifier mechanism to work without *values* per se...just to isolate the mechanism. I assume most `Tag`s would have values...but perhaps there are exceptions.

```
public interface ITag : IObservable<ITag>, IObserver<ITag>, IDisposable
{
  Type TagType { get; }
  bool SubscribeToTag( ITag tag );
}

public class Tag : ITag
{
  protected readonly List<Subscription> observables = new List<Subscription>( );
  protected readonly List<IObserver<ITag>> observers = new List<IObserver<ITag>>( );
  bool disposedValue = false;

  protected Tag( ) { }

  IDisposable IObservable<ITag>.Subscribe( IObserver<ITag> observer )
  {
    if ( !observers.Contains( observer ) )
    {
      observers.Add( observer );
      observer.OnNext( this ); //--> or not...maybe you'd set some InitialSubscription state 
                               //--> to help the observer distinguish initial notification from changes
    }
    return new Subscription( this, observer, observers );
  }

  public bool SubscribeToTag( ITag tag )
  {
    if ( observables.Any( subscription => subscription.Tag == tag ) ) return false; //--> could throw here
    observables.Add( ( Subscription ) tag.Subscribe( this ) );
    return true;
  }

  protected void Notify( ) => observers.ForEach( observer => observer.OnNext( this ) );

  public virtual void OnNext( ITag value ) { }

  public virtual void OnError( Exception error ) { }

  public virtual void OnCompleted( ) { }

  public Type TagType => GetType( );

  protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing )
  {
    if ( !disposedValue )
    {
      if ( disposing )
      {
        while ( observables.Count > 0 )
        {
          var sub = observables[ 0 ];
          observables.RemoveAt( 0 );
          ( ( IDisposable ) sub ).Dispose( );
        }
      }
      disposedValue = true;
    }
  }

  public void Dispose( )
  {
    Dispose( true );
  }

  protected sealed class Subscription : IDisposable
  {
    readonly WeakReference<Tag> tag;
    readonly List<IObserver<ITag>> observers;
    readonly IObserver<ITag> observer;

    internal Subscription( Tag tag, IObserver<ITag> observer, List<IObserver<ITag>> observers )
    {
      this.tag = new WeakReference<Tag>( tag );
      this.observers = observers;
      this.observer = observer;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose( )
    {
      if ( observers.Contains( observer ) ) observers.Remove( observer );
    }

    public Tag Tag
    {
      get
      {
        if ( tag.TryGetTarget( out Tag target ) )
        {
          return target;
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If absolutely all tags have values, you could merge the following implementation with the foregoing...but I think it just feels better to separate them out.

```
public interface ITag<T> : ITag
{
  T OriginalValue { get; }
  T Value { get; set; }
  bool IsReadOnly { get; }
}

public class Tag<T> : Tag, ITag<T>
{
  T currentValue;

  public Tag( T value, bool isReadOnly = true ) : base( )
  {
    IsReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    OriginalValue = value;
    currentValue = value;
  }

  public bool IsReadOnly { get; }

  public T OriginalValue { get; }

  public T Value
  {
    get
    {
      return currentValue;
    }
    set
    {
      if ( IsReadOnly ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "You should have checked!" );
      if ( Value != null && !Value.Equals( value ) )
      {
        currentValue = value;
        Notify( );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While this looks a bit busy, it's mostly vanilla subscription mechanics and disposability. The derived types would be drop-dead simple.

Notice the protected `Notify()` method. I started off putting that into the interface, but realized that it's probably not a good idea to make that accessible from the outside world.

So...onto examples; here's a sample `Author`. Notice how the `AddBook` sets up mutual relations. Not every type would have a method like this...but it illustrates how easy it is to do:

```
public class Author : Tag<string>
{
  public Author( string name ) : base( name ) { }

  public void AddBook( Book book )
  {
    SubscribeToTag( book );
    book.SubscribeToTag( this );
  }

  public IEnumerable<Book> Books
  {
    get
    {
      return
        observables
        .Where( o => o.Tag is Book )
        .Select( o => ( Book ) o.Tag );
    }
  }

  public override void OnNext( ITag value )
  {
    switch ( value.TagType.Name )
    {
      case nameof( Book ):
        Console.WriteLine( $"{( ( Book ) value ).CurrentValue} happened to {CurrentValue}" );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

...and `Book` would be similar. Another thought regarding the mutual relation; if you accidentally defined the relation both through `Book` and `Author`, there's no harm, no foul...because the subscription mechanism just quietly skips duplications (I tested the case just to be sure):

```
public class Book : Tag<string>
{
  public Book( string name ) : base( name ) { }

  public void AddAuthor( Author author )
  {
    SubscribeToTag( author );
    author.SubscribeToTag( this );
  }

  public IEnumerable<Author> Authors
  {
    get
    {
      return
        observables
        .Where( o => o.Tag is Author )
        .Select( o => ( Author ) o.Tag );
    }
  }

  public override void OnNext( ITag value )
  {
    switch ( value.TagType.Name )
    {
      case nameof( Author ):
        Console.WriteLine( $"{( ( Author ) value ).CurrentValue} happened to {CurrentValue}" );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

...and finally, a little test harness to see if any of it works:

```
var book = new Book( "Pride and..." );
var author = new Author( "Jane Doe" );

book.AddAuthor( author );

Console.WriteLine( "\nbook's authors..." );
foreach ( var writer in book.Authors )
{
  Console.WriteLine( writer.Value );
}

Console.WriteLine( "\nauthor's books..." );
foreach ( var tome in author.Books )
{
  Console.WriteLine( tome.Value );
}

author.AddBook( book ); //--> maybe an error

Console.WriteLine( "\nbook's authors..." );
foreach ( var writer in book.Authors )
{
  Console.WriteLine( writer.Value );
}

Console.WriteLine( "\nauthor's books..." );
foreach ( var tome in author.Books )
{
  Console.WriteLine( tome.Value );
}
```

...which spit out this:

```
Jane Doe happened to Pride and...
Pride and... happened to Jane Doe

book's authors...
Jane Doe

author's books...
Pride and...

book's authors...
Jane Doe

author's books...
Pride and...
```

While I had the list properties being `IEnumerable<T>`, you could make them be lazily loaded lists. You'd need to be able to invalidate the list's backing store, but that might flow pretty naturally from your observables.

There are hundreds of ways to go with all this. I tried to not get carried away. Don't know...it would take some testing to figure out how practical this is...but it was sure fun to think about.

**EDIT**

Something I forgot to illustrate...bookmarks. I guess a bookmark's value is an updateable page number? Something like:

```
public class Bookmark : Tag<int>
{
  public Bookmark( Book book, int pageNumber ) : base( pageNumber, false )
  {
    SubscribeToTag( book );
    book.SubscribeToTag( this );
  }

  public Book Book
  {
    get
    {
      return
        observables
        .Where( o => o.Tag is Book )
        .Select( o => o.Tag as Book )
        .FirstOrDefault( ); //--> could be .First( ) if you null-check book in ctor
    }
  }
}
```

Then, a `Book` might have an `IEnumerable<Bookmark>` property:

```
public class Book : Tag<string>
{
  //--> omitted stuff... <--//

  public IEnumerable<Bookmark> Bookmarks
  {
    get
    {
      return
        observables
        .Where( o => o.Tag is Bookmark )
        .Select( o => ( Bookmark ) o.Tag );
    }
  }

  //--> omitted stuff... <--//
}
```

The neat thing about that, is authors' bookmarks are their books' bookmarks:

```
public class Author : Tag<string>
{
   //--> omitted stuff... <--//

   public IEnumerable<Bookmark> Bookmarks => Books.SelectMany( b => b.Bookmarks );

   //--> omitted stuff... <--//
}
```

For yuks, I made the bookmark take a book on construction...just to illustrate a different approach. Mix and match as needed ;-) Notice that the bookmark doesn't have a list of books...just a single book...because that more correctly fits the model. It's interesting to realize that you could resolve all a books bookmarks from a single bookmark:

```
var bookmarks = new List<Bookmark>( bookmark.Book.Bookmarks );
```

...and just as easily get all the authors bookmarks:

```
var authBookmarks = new List<Bookmark>( bookmark.Book.Authors.SelectMany( a=> a.Bookmarks ) );
```

Comment: so if we were to add `var language = new Language("English")`, I would then have to do `book.AddLanguage(language)` as well as `author.AddLanguage(language)` ?

Comment: Well...not necessarily. You can ad-hoc add any tag through the SubscribeToTag method. You wouldn't necessarily have a strongly typed way to interrogate it...but you could expose your enumerables in any way that seems appropriate.

Comment: The `AddAuthor` and `AddBook` I just threw in for illustration. It's very loosely architected. You can tighten up what you want. For example, you could make a virtual `ReadRelations` method that provides the sole method for adding tags if you want. Your strongly typed enumerable properties in the base types may or may not find  matching tags at run time. No harm no foul. There's no hard-and-fast rules unless you impose them.

Comment: I added a little more...just to illustrate bookmarks and their possible implications for the model.

Comment: think i'm going to try this. you should come by the WPF chat channel sometime. would be great to have you around.https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: Great - I hope you have some luck with it. It was really fun to put together.

Comment: IT IS WORKING SO AWESOME THANK YOU

Comment: Oh, my pleasure,@Julien! Thanks for the huge bump :-)

Answer (score 4):

> Is using Book as a source of truth not a good approach?

Think of your current setup as a relational database schema where no tables except for `Book` have a foreign key reference pointing to anything else. You always have to scan through the `Book` table to find any relationships containing books. In the example you gave, you have to walk the entire collection of books to find all the books created by a single author. If you had references going back the other direction, you would only have to find the single author, then look at its `Books` property.

How would you currently get the list of authors that haven't written any books? You'd have to scan the list of books to get a list of every author that *does* have a book, then find each author *not* in that list.

> How can I expose this kind of information to each non-Book tag type without giving each Author or Bookmark access to the global item collection (which feels like a big no-no), or maintaining lists of all relevant tags for each tag type (which just feels really painfully inefficient)?

You're going to need properties that represent every tag type on every item — there's really no way around that. If you want the items in a list to be sorted based on the number of bookmarks that each of them has, then each one needs to offer up the number of bookmarks it has.

But properties don't have to be backed by precomputed lists. They can effectively be instructions about how to do the appropriate joins to get the needed information. For example, the `Bookmarks` property of `Author` would use the `Books` property to get a list of bookmarks:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Bookmark> Bookmarks => this.Books.SelectMany(b => b.Bookmarks);
```

You could also cache the result, if you wanted.

If you choose to continute not to have references from any entity back to `Book` and instead made `MyItems` available within your model classes, you could do the same sort of thing for relationships pointing to `Book`. For example, in `Author`:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Book> Books => MyItems.OfType<Book>.Where(b => b.Authors.Contains(this));
```

I don't recommend doing this, though, as you are correct about it not feeling right. It chains your model's implementation to a separate, non-related data structure. My recommendation is to implement direct relationships with lists, and use computed properties for everything else you want to sort by.

Comment: thanks. this is a good approach i've used myself since asking this question. it does work fairly well. hopefully i will have time to get back to my project and elaborate on what works and what doesnt work when going this route, which is basically a mix of pre-computed as well as live collections based on the type in question.  one issue i've run into is parent collections will not see changes of collections that have already been computed, which leaves me with a ton of event listeners all over the place to live sort my lists

Comment: question: are you recommending that I mirror all the relationships?  Eg. should `Book` be populated with the live list of `Author` as well as have all my `Author`s populated with live lists of their books?  Ideally I would only be using one master view model for each object, so that changes like updating a name or description are seen everywhere and kept in sync.

Comment: I do recommend that, because those relationships are an important part of your data model, although if you really don't need it for anything I don't see a problem leaving it out. I don't think I understand your comment about "one master view model for each object" or how this would prevent that. Regarding event listeners, yes, that's just how it goes: you need to emit and respond to events to trigger refreshes in models where things may be changing.

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with using Entity Framework for this? It's intended to solve all of these kinds of problems. You may not want to use it in your final implementation, but looking at how it does things may give you some ideas/inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, I would use Id's for the Books, Authors and perhaps even Bookmarks.
Any relation between a Book/Author can be captured by the Book having the Author Id, and an Author having a Book Id for example. It also guarantees that Books/Authors will be unique.

Why do you feel the need to let the Book, Author and Bookmark class inherit from the same base class? Is there shared functionality you want to be using?

For the functionality you're seeking, I'd say making some extension methods could be really useful, for example

```
int GetWrittenBooks(this Author author)
{
    //either query your persistent storage or look it up in memory
}
```

I'd say, make sure you don't put too much functionality in your classes. For example your Book class doesn't have any responsibilities regarding a possible Author birthday, for example. If the birthday of an Author would be  in the Author class, the Book shouldn't have access to the birthday of the author, neither should it have Authors, but just references to authors. The book would just be "interested" in which author it has, nothing more/less.

The same goes for an Author: it doesn't have anything to do with the amount of letters on page 150 of Book x, for example. That's the responsibility of the book and it shouldn't concern the author.

tl;dr: [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)/[Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: Yes. I could track a books authors via ids, and an authors books via ids. but as you add more tags this process becomes very cumbersome.  also, using ids alone does now allow for wpf databinding. the viewmodels need relationships to the other viewmodels. i can't view an `Author` and have the wpf databinding engine somehow use my custom `GetWrittenBooks` function.  and again, imagine how the complexity grows with more tag types.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can approach this with a standard entity model approach as with any database, just in your case your database is in-memory.

```
public class Repository
{
    public List<Book> GetBooksByAuthor(Author author) {} // books by author
    public List<Author> GetAuthors() {}
    // ...
}
```

another positive here is you can implement each lookup in a way that is more efficient.
you can introduce an interface to the `Repository` if you want to swap it for a database later on.

every entity can hold a reference back to repository and thus you can provide aliases on entity level for convinience:

```
public class Author
{
    private Repository repo;
    public Author(Repository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    // ... 
    public List<Book> Books => this.repo.GetBooksByAuthor(this);
}
```

depending on how data integrity is important you can also opt to other forms of collections, that would prevent modifications on queries, or hold changes list to each entity and so on.

if it's an internal library many of such concerns may be lifted to simplify code.

Comment: the question clearly states it is a unified list.  I cannot have seperate lists for each type of item.  I am also not interested in a solution that involves creating dozens to hundreds `Get X By Y` functions